What is causing this memory leak when using riverpod and fl_chart?
I want to have more than one chart and when I hover on one I want it to update and show the hover on the other charts.
To achieve this I store the hover "state" using riverpod and then all charts listen for it and then draw with the hovered location. I use the touchCallback provided by fl_chart to make this work.
Am I miss-using riverpod or fl_charts API's with this method or is it a bug in fl_chart? I am getting a bad memory leak of fl_chart objects doing this. The objects grow quickly when hovering and don't reduce.
Its easy to see the FlSpot objects as they grow so quick, it starts with 4501 objects, 3 lines of 1500 points. Then hovering makes these increase into the millions fast. It's not only these objects, it is also other fl_chart objects like titles etc.
Below is a simpler full project that reproduces the issue with 2 charts.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Chart(),),
              Expanded(child: Chart(),),
            ]
          )
        )
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
    );
  }
}

final testProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

class Chart extends ConsumerWidget {
  Chart({super.key});

  static const int _numberOfLines = 3;
  static const int _numberOfDataPoints = 1500;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final int index = ref.watch(testProvider);

    return LineChart(
      LineChartData(
        lineTouchData: LineTouchData(
          handleBuiltInTouches: false,
          touchSpotThreshold: 20,
          touchCallback: (final FlTouchEvent ev, final LineTouchResponse? res) {
            ref.read(testProvider.notifier).state = res?.lineBarSpots?.first.spotIndex ?? 0;
          },
        ),
        gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
        borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
        lineBarsData: _buildLineData(index),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<LineChartBarData> _buildLineData(final int index) {
    final List<LineChartBarData> lineData = <LineChartBarData>[];

    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfLines; ++i) {
      lineData.add(LineChartBarData(
        showingIndicators: <int>[index],
        dotData: FlDotData(show: false),
        spots: () {
          return List<FlSpot>.generate(
            _numberOfDataPoints,
            (index) {
              return FlSpot(index.toDouble(), index.toDouble());
            }
          );
        }()
      ));
    }

    return lineData;
  }
}


Tricky.  I wonder how many events touchCallback is sending ? If you do a print statement there you'll get a feel - perhaps it's a gazillion, in which case you're recreating all your graphs a gazillion times.  In that case, it may be worth trying to do some debouncing, and the riverpod docs have a section on that.

@JonMountjoy It is true that the charts redraw every time I move the mouse over the charts. This isn't ideal but I don't think there is any other option in fl_chart :(
Even If I am re creating the charts on every frame, shouldn't the charts from the previous frames be freed?
I will look into debouncing!
